# Best smartphone data plan in South Korea?

Tags: cellphones, south-korea, data-plans

What is the best way to get smartphone access when traveling for a few days in South Korea? I am mostly interested in getting cheap data access (google maps...).

Comment: For this question's Siamese twin, see **[Cell phones in Japan](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3490/cell-phones-in-japan)**

Comment: One is about South Korea and the other one about Japan

Comment: Wouldn't its *Siamese* twin be [this one](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13086/mobile-providers-and-mobile-internet-in-thailand)?

Answer (score 5):

I used [iPhoneTrip](http://iphonetrip.com), now called [KeepGo](http://www.keepgo.com/), once for this sort of thing, and was happy.

They will rent you a SIM card or a cell phone that works wherever you are going.

Comment: A similar option is http://www.onesimcard.com/ - (also scammy-looking!).

Comment: Actually iphonetrip's site looks a lot better than it did a year or two ago.

Comment: This answer would be a lot better if it told us briefly what iphonetrip.com is and/or does.

Comment: Will the phone be waiting for you in the destination city or do they get it to you before you leave home? Is it available no matter which country you are from / depart from / go to?

Comment: The latter: when I used it, they FedEx'd me a SIM card.  They also rented entire phones, but of course that costs more.

Answer (score 4):

All major Korean cell-phone network providers (SKT,KT,LG) have their booth at the airport. They rent cell phones with daily charges.

If you can read Korean, [look here](http://www.airport.kr/airport/facility/falicityInfo.iia?carId=26&facilityId=87).

You can also rent data sharing devices called **egg** (KT) or **bridge** (SKT). You can use them to get wifi wherever you can get cell service.

Answer (score 2):

It is cheaper to buy a used cell phone, a pre-paid contract, and sell the phone back before you leave. It's quite common for regular (non-smart) phones. The procedure can take up to an hour, since you don't have a Korean ID and clerk will have to call/fax/etc some head office or support line to get your number registered to your passport.

Renting a phone is an option, but it is expensive.

Nowadays I think you can get a pre-parid microsim for your own GSM/LTE smartphone. All modern high-end smartphones are quite capable; coverage won't be as good as native's, but I think it will be good enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can rent a so called "egg" from various website like www.taobao.com and it provides wifi hotspot, then you can use your cell phone connect to it and use apps like google map. I rented for less than $10 per day, and the data is unlimited. Speed is decent too.